# Theme settings reset to default on plugins update

Tags: wordpress

A few time I have faced this problem.
this one time 
 when I have updated a plugin, the whole website theme goes to default, all of my custom style (footer design, navbar, banner) are vanished and replaced with default appearance which came with the theme. Which simply means all of my customizations are gone.
So, next time I have created a child theme first and made all the changes in that ...but same when I have reactivated the parent theme ...it asked for install some built-in plugins and then again default settings, contents ....
I am new in WordPress.so don't know what is wrong.

In the case of the WP site, I try to do customization from appearance > editor but most of the time changes do not take place, because of cache-related plugins. So, disabling those plugins is the way (I think) to make changes.......
But, then this problem arises (default content).

Comment: Maybe you are doing something wrong, that's why your child theme doesn't work.
Which theme are you using? and the plugins recommended by the theme?

Comment: child theme works (changes takes place) but after reactivating the parent theme it begins from the start like I just downloaded it and want to install it (like parent theme is completely new) but its not parent theme had some changes...
yeah the plugins are recommended by theme
theme - shopkeeper

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Now I understand your issue. You don't have to activate the `parent theme` if `child theme` is available. The child theme will call the parent theme. Just activate the child theme. :)

Comment: thanks,
but what if I don't like the new changes in the child theme and I want to revert to the parent theme? what to do then, because if I reactivate the parent theme it will start from the beginning as I told you...
what I want to do .....!!! (scenario)
I have a parent theme and I have made some changes in that .....
Now, I got some idea and want to customize the theme but don't want to finalize it, I want a child theme where I can play around and in the end, if anything goes wrong I just want to go back to the parent theme (with old changes)...
how do you do that?
thanks in advance